# What movie has aliens hunt people using living tentacled discs?

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I saw a movie in the 80's where aliens were hunting people — from what I remember in the woods, or a real rural area — and they would throw these living disc-like creatures with small tentacles on them at the humans.

What movie was this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"[Without Warning](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081764/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)"?

It had a town that was attacked by an alien being who threw round disc like creatures at people that killed them. Here's a trailer on YouTube:

Comment: Awe you are the man. I try to scroll through netflix hulu and many others trying to find this. Thank you so much. IDKW but the age I was when I was it, it always stuck with me and wanted to revisit the movie

Comment: @user23850 - I'm the same as you. One of my favorite movies as a kid. Scared the bejesus out of me. Glad to have been of help! Don't forget to accept this answer.

Comment: It haunted me in my dreams after I saw that it as a 9 year old girl on Creature Features... I couldn't dodge the flying discs that landed and spread its bloodsucking veins. I think there's a black and white version from the 60s because I think it was a double feature with NOTLD. Scared me enough to remember 35 yrs ago from seeing it ONCE.

Answer (score 3):

[Without Warning](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081764/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

A most underrated B-Movie of the 80's and (un-officially) the precursor of the movie 'Predator'. This fact will be highly contested given the fact that the writers of 'Predator' (at least to my knowledge) have never publically admitted to having based the ideas for the highly popular version with Arnold Schwarzenegger on this awesome and obscure gem, which came out just 7 years prior; however, let's go over the similarities:

1. Unlike in most alien films of the time, this alien does not come to observe, attempt to communicate or invade the planet. Instead he comes to hunt for sport and take trophies, just like the '87 masterpiece.
2. Just like in 'Predator', the alien has a code of conduct, only killing people in possession of or in close proximity to a weapon and allowing to escape weaker beings, e.g. the cub scout children.
3. The alien throws a flying disc, just like the predator hunter, albeit not a mechanical one, but a biological equivalent.
4. Cast member Martin Landau's character has a military background and metaphorically refers to human society as a 'jungle'.
5. After killing its prey, the bodies will be hanged.
6. And best of all, the alien on 'Without Warning' is played by none other than 'Kevin Peter Hall', the very basketball player turned actor who would go on to play the Predator. ;)

All in all, this is a must see movie for any true 'Predator' fan.

Many thanks to my beloved wife 'Kesja Krepitation', former sci-fi website moderator in Europe and all-around expert on the subject, for having pointed all of this out.