# Name this early 80's sci fi/alien movie?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I don't remember much about this movie but it's stuck in my mind and I would like to know what it is.  I saw it on HBO in the early 80's, probably somewhere between 81 and 83.  There is what I think is an alien that has some kind of weapon like a large throwing star that either attaches to or is embedded in his leg.  He goes around killing people in a rural area, mostly at night.  That's about all I remember.  Help.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *[Without Warning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_Warning_(1980_film))*?

[image: DVD cover]

> A father and son go hunting in the mountains. Before they can begin hunting, which the son does not want to do anyway, they are killed by flying jellyfish-like creatures, which penetrate their skin with needle-tipped tentacles.
>
> Some time later, four teenagers, Tom, Greg, Beth and Sandy, hike in the same area, ignoring the warnings of local truck stop owner Joe Taylor (Jack Palance). A group of cub scouts is also in the area; their leader (Larry Storch) is also killed by the alien creatures, while his troop runs into an unidentified humanoid and flee.

The humanoid alien is throwing the disc-shaped creatures. The following is a trailer where you can see it throwing them (contains spoilers on the fate of one of the characters):

Comment: If it is this movie, it's a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51838/what-movie-has-aliens-hunt-people-using-living-tentacled-discs